# How to save gensim doc2vec model

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

after train the model, I use  infer_vector() to get the vector successfully.
but after I save the model and load again, error appears as follows:

```
print "infer:", model.infer_vector(sents[0]).tolist()
File "/Users/zhangweimin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 752, in infer_vector
    doctag_vectors=doctag_vectors, doctag_locks=doctag_locks)
File "gensim/models/doc2vec_inner.pyx", line 426, in gensim.models.doc2vec_inner.train_document_dm (./gensim/models/doc2vec_inner.c:5401)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

the whole code is:`

```
model = train_d2v(labeled_docs, model_file, word_file, 3)

# OK
print "before infer:", model.infer_vector(sents[0]).tolist()

model = Doc2Vec.load(model_file)

print "sents[0]:", sents[0]
print "type:", type(model)
print "infer:", model.infer_vector(sents[0]).tolist() #ERROR`
```

Comment: What's your code for saving the model?

Comment: What does `train_d2v()` do? Are you using the most recent version of `gensim`

Comment: thx the version of my gensim is 1.0.0.   I print gensim.__version__ get it. and I use model.save() to save model.

Comment: def train_d2v(docs, model_file, word_file, epoch_cnt = 10, if_shuffle=True, learn_rate = 0.025, dec_lr = 0.002):
    model = Doc2Vec(alpha=learn_rate, size=100, window=8, min_count=5, workers=4)
    log_info("build vocab...")
    model.build_vocab(docs)
    for epoch in range(epoch_cnt):
        model.train(docs)
        model.alpha -= dec_lr
        model.min_alpha = model.alpha  # fix the learning rate, no decay
    model.save(model_file)
    return model

Comment: It may be best t edit the question to add information, so the formatting is correct. What do the earlier lines of your code print, before the error is shown?

Comment: Thanks. When I update the gensim to version 2.1.0, it works and save model correctly. The old version is 1.0.0. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments above, using a more-recent version of gensim (2.1.0) resolved the issue.